# Typescript: Object is possibly null when creating method

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an "Object is possibly null" error when creating the changePageSize method inside book-store.component.html. Apparently I have to initialize the object in the class, but I'm not sure how to do that, can anyone help me out. I am new to Typescript and Angular.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUzFl.png]

[image]

Comment: Do not post code or error messages as images - include it directly in your question as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$event.target` has type `EventTarget`. It has no `value` field.
That's the reason of your issue.

To fix this issue you need to cast `$event.target` to correct type.

```js
// template
<select ... (change)="changePageSize($event)">...</select>

// component
changePageSize(event: Event): void {
    const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const value = element.value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed the errors. However, when I try to select number of items per page, it gives me a blank screen.

Comment: @koda I provided only solution to your main question. So please approve it if it fixed your issue. If you have another issue just create new question with all required code (component / template), but as already was mentioned by kaya3 post it as a text with stackoverflow code formatting.